# Docker-compose and pm2 - way to filter log messages?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, mean-stack, pm2

Environment: Docker-compose, pm2, MEAN app

Is there a way to filter on only certain `console.log` messages in the `docker-compose` logging console and suppress the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running `docker-compose up -d`, you can always then use standard CLI tools like `grep` on piped data from `docker-compose logs -f`

So, basically something like this, `docker-compose logs -f | grep 'TAG'`